# How does the JavaScript Import work under the hood?

Tags: javascript

How does the `import` statement actually work in JavaScript? I read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and it says that it places exported code within the scope of the file. Does that mean that the code is copied over into the file where I type import?

For example - in library.js I have:

```
export {export function getUsefulContents(url, callback) {
    getJSON(url, data => callback(JSON.parse(data)));
}
```

In main.js I have:

```
import { getUsefulContents} from 'library.js';

getUsefulContents('http://www.example.com',
    data => { doSomethingUseful(data); });
```

**This allows me to call getUsefulContents() in main.js. My question is, does main.js now have the contents that I exported from library.js?**

**Is using `import` the same as just having physically defined `getUsefulContents()` in main.js?**

```
function getUsefulContents(url, callback) {
    getJSON(url, data => callback(JSON.parse(data)));
}

getUsefulContents('http://www.example.com',
    data => { doSomethingUseful(data); });
```

The main reason why I ask is because I want to know if using import will have an effect on main.js file size? Or is something else going on under the hood?

Thank you!

Comment: file size would stay the same, however the environment run-time will get bigger as it will store more data in memory not into the file itself. Exports is just a new module system that is being was implemented in [ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

*Is using import the same as just having physically defined getUsefulContents() in main.js?* basically just now the environment has to implement the module loader in the runtime so chrome **V8**, firefox **SpiderMonkey**

Comment: This might help: https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-abstract-module-records

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are using `main.js`. If you run it through a bundler, then the bundler will probably include `library.js` into `main.js` to pack it up into one file. In that case, the only advantage would be maintainability and ease of development because you are focused on the file you are working on. If you are simply running the `import` statement and deploying your application, the `import` statement won't affect the file size of `main.js`.

Answer (score 0):

It just namespacing it within the file that you are importing it to so

any code from useful-library.js is included in the file, I visualize it this way

```
import { usefulCodeFromLibrary } from './useful-library.js'; 

((usefulCodeFromLibrary)=>{
  // My excellent code
  
  // Imported code doing it's job
  usefulCodeFromLibrary.someHelperFunction()
}()
```